# Extracting Subject-Object-Verb from a sentance

Tags: parsing, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

How to extratc SOV from a sentance using popular NLP libraries. I have read that one method is to generate a dependency structure and convert it to SOV structure.

Answer (score 2):

In StanfordCoreNLP, you can take a look at our [Dependency Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/nndep.shtml), which produces dependency trees (`SemanticGraph`s) that can be queried using [Semgrex](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/semgraph/semgrex/SemgrexPattern.html). For example, with the pattern

```
{pos:/V.*/}=verb >/.subj.*/ {}=subject >/.obj.*/ {}=object
```

Alternately, the [Stanford OpenIE system](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.shtml) may be of interest. To a first approximation, I think what you're looking for is the extraction of OpenIE `(subject; relation; object)` triples. In this same vein, the University of Washington has a number of OpenIE systems that you can take a look at: [Ollie](http://knowitall.github.io/ollie/) and the more recent [OpenIE4](http://knowitall.github.io/openie/).